# .htaccess redirect according to referral existence

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect every url that **does not** contain `?ref=something`, to a fixed html page.

Example:

Action: user navigates to www.domain.com/?ref=somerefcode. Result: stay on the page.

Action: user lands on www.domain.com **without** ref tag. Result: should be redirected to: www.domain.com/other_page

Thank you very much!

Ronen

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ref=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/other_page$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /other_page [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sergio!

A little correction to fit my question exactly:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ref=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^ref=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /other_page [R,L]
```